# How to handle same intent filter for two activities?

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking

I am trying to implement deep linking in my app. I have two activities: SplashScreenActivity and MainActivity. Both activities have the same intent filter, such as:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <data
                android:host="product"
                android:scheme="gg" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
        android:name="com.example.SplashScreenActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="product"
                android:scheme="gg" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

What i do is: when app is already open, i want MainActivity to be triggered and when app is not open i want splashScreenActivity to be triggered. But a popup appears and expects me to choose one of these activities, i do not want that. I want it to be automatically chosen. So, how can i implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

-> First of all, you **don't want to have multiple options** to choose means you want only one option. So simply you should **have only one `Activity` to handle** such event.

i.e.: As mentioned below, you should have `DeepLinkingActivity` in manifest file.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.DeepLinkingActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <data
                android:host="product"
                android:scheme="gg" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
        android:name="com.example.MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
        android:name="com.example.SplashScreenActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

-> You want to **decide the next flow based upon some condition** like whether your app is in foreground or not, so simply put that logic in `DeepLinkingActivity` and make sure you don't setup any layout file for that activity.

i.e.:

```
private boolean isAppInForeground(Context ctx) {
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) ctx.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningTaskInfo> services = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    if (services == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (services.size() > 0 && services.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(ctx.getApplicationContext().getPackageName().toString())) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Based upon above logic, you may redirect the user to either `SplashScreenActivity` or `MainActivity`.

**Note:**

As you want to retrieve currently going on tasks, you will need to add below permission in your manifest file.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i will try and see it. But just one thing: accoording to this scenario, shouldn't the DeepLinkingActivity be the launcher activity?

Comment: @bigO: No. When you add any activity in `Launcher` category, it simply means it will be the first activity which will be open when user taps on your app icon. You might want to open `DeepLinkingActivity` only when there some event related to your host `product` and scheme `gg` fired.

Comment: isAppInForeround always returned true for me but with some modification, i managed to make it work so i am accepting this as an answer. Just one more quick question: if my app starts from the deeplinking, when i press back button and want to exit the app, the app restarts as soon as it is closed. What might be the reason for that?

Comment: @bigO: how exactly do you start your app?

Comment: i start it from adb with the following command:  ./adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "gg://product/136658071" com.example.mypackagename

Comment: @bigO: AFAIK, it is capturing the Intent again and that's why it gets start again. I would suggest to try with some real scenario instead of adb.

Answer (score 4):

You face expected behavior. If you have two activities handle same intent you will facing chooser dialog.

Remove `Intent-filter` from MainActivity, and add `android:launchMode=singleTask`:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.gittigidiyormobil.MainActivity" 
    android:launchMode=singleTask>
</activity>

<activity
        android:name="com.gittigidiyormobil.SplashScreenActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="product"
                android:scheme="gg" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And just post you `Intent` through SplashScreenActivity to MainActivity and handle `Intent` in `onNewEvent` and in `onCreate` functions. [more about `launchMode`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i will try and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

In your case you are using both Launcher and Default for a single Activity(SplashScreenActivity) that is the problem. For your need first check the application is open or not. If the application is open before  setcontentview method in this SplashScreenActivity start the mainActivity. if application is not open start SplashScreenActivity. Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Thanks, but the popup appears before any of the activities are triggered, and says: "Complete the action using ..." and forces me to choose one of them, and then splashscreen or mainactivity starts. So i cannot make a check before that. But i will remove the default category from splashscreen and try again